# Metronome app with GUI

Tags: python, object-oriented

I have a working metronome app with a GUI, built using Python. I use an Android app called [Pro Metronome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eumlab.android.prometronome&hl=en_GB&pli=1) which I like, and I wanted to build a simplified version of it as a project. My goal was to have accurate timing (including actively correcting for drift due to integer truncation), and to have nice behaviour when changing tempo and/or time signature during playback.

I would like to learn how to better design my code, and follow best practices. My study thus far often leads to quite trivial examples that I have difficulty applying to a project like this. Thanks in advance to anyone who is able to offer their advice.

---

I am revisiting this code after a few months. Here are my observations so far:

**Overall:**

- Incomplete docstrings for methods.
- No leading underscores applied to indicate intended access for attributes and methods.

**metronome_master_GH.py:**

`Metronome` class:

- The `__init__` method is very long.
- Some attributes should be constants.
- The `get_next_audio_block` method is very long.

**metronome_tkinter_master_GH.py**

`App` class:

- The `__init__` method is long.
- There is coupling between the `Metronome` and `App`. I intended to implement an MVC design to remove this.
- There are some numbers defining GUI element positions and sizes which should be defined as variables, perhaps in a `config` file.
- The `make_widgets` method is very long.
- Some of the methods should probably belong to the `BeatSoundLabel` class instead.

---

This [GitHub repo](https://github.com/rg1990/python-metronome) contains the full code plus images and audio files. Here is the code for review:

## metronome_master_GH.py

```
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
import audiofile
import sys
import queue
import threading


class Metronome():
    def __init__(self, tempo=180, beats_per_bar=4):
        # Define limits for tempo and beats_per_bar
        self.min_tempo = 10
        self.max_tempo = 350
        self.min_beats_per_bar = 1
        self.max_beats_per_bar = 8
        
        # Input validation
        if tempo < self.min_tempo or tempo > self.max_tempo:
            raise Exception(f"Tempo must be between {self.min_tempo} and {self.max_tempo}.")
        
        if beats_per_bar < self.min_beats_per_bar or beats_per_bar > self.max_beats_per_bar:
            raise Exception(f"Value for beats_per_bar must be between {self.min_beats_per_bar} and {self.max_beats_per_bar}.")
        
        
        self.tempo = tempo
        self.beats_per_bar = beats_per_bar
        
        # State attribute
        self.running = False
        
        # Used for changing tempo while playing
        self.new_tempo = None   
        self.tempo_change_pending = False
        
        # Load and define the arrays of samples for different click sounds
        self.fs = 16000     # sample rate of audio, in Hz
        self.hi, _ = audiofile.read("./samples/hi.wav")
        self.lo, _ = audiofile.read("./samples/lo.wav")
        self.empty_click = np.zeros_like(self.lo)
        
        
        # Define attributes for use with audio stream
        self.BLOCKSIZE = 512    # samples per block of audio
        # TODO - write code to pre-fill the queue
        self.BUFFERSIZE = 10    # blocks of audio to pre-fill queue with
        self.TIMEOUT = self.BLOCKSIZE * self.BUFFERSIZE / self.fs
        
        self.q = queue.Queue(maxsize=self.BUFFERSIZE)
        self.event = threading.Event()
        self.stream = self.create_stream()
        
        
        # Instantiate attributes related to click timing
        self.num_samples_until_next_click = 0
        self.float_interval = self.fs * 60.0 / self.tempo
        self.interval = int(self.fs * 60.0 / self.tempo)
        self.interval_samples_elapsed = 0
        
        # Create a block of zeros to deliver to the stream between clicks
        self.zero_array = np.zeros(self.BLOCKSIZE)
        
        # Instantiate some counters
        self.total_samples_delivered = 0
        self.current_beat = 0
        self.beat_to_show = 0
        self.beats_at_tempo = 0
        self.bars_to_play_at_tempo = None   # for playing a specific number of bars
        
        # Set up the array that determines which click sound to use for each beat
        self.beat_click_indices = self.create_beat_click_index_array()
        self.click_sounds = np.array([self.empty_click, self.lo, self.hi])
        # Initialise a dictionary with click sound choice for each beat, using default values
        self.update_beat_sample_dict(self.beat_click_indices)
        # bool for improved code readability
        self.click_is_due_in_this_block = False  
        
        # Drift error compensation
        self.accumulated_drift_error = 0.0
        self.drift_error_per_block = self.compute_drift_error_per_block()
        self.samples_to_shift = 0
        
        # For plotting and saving to WAV for analysis
        self.full_output = []
        # Store the "tail" of a click that spans 2 adjacent arrays of size self.BLOCKSIZE
        self.tail_array = None  
        
        
    # TODO - Speed trainer is in development
    # def enable_trainer(self, start_tempo, bars_at_tempo, bpm_increase, num_increases):
    #     self.trainer_enabled = True
    #     self.trainer_start_tempo = start_tempo
    #     self.trainer_bars_at_tempo = bars_at_tempo
    #     self.trainer_bpm_increase = bpm_increase
    #     self.trainer_num_increases = num_increases
        
    #     self.trainer_end_tempo = self.trainer_start_tempo + (self.trainer_num_increases * self.trainer_bpm_increase)
        

    # def disable_trainer(self):
    #     self.trainer_active = False
        
        
    
    def pre_fill_queue(self):
        # Range is (BUFFERSIZE-1) because the first callback will add a block too
        # and otherwise we get an exception because the queue is already full.
        for _ in range(self.BUFFERSIZE-1):
            next_audio_block, beat = self.get_next_audio_block()
            # Debugging print statements to check output
            # print(f"Mean: {np.mean(next_audio_block)}")
            # print(f"Queue size before putting: {self.q.qsize()}")
            if not len(next_audio_block):
                break
            self.q.put_nowait([next_audio_block, beat])
            # Append the new audio block to full_output for later examination
            self.full_output.append(next_audio_block)
    
    
    def create_stream(self):        
        # Create an OutputStream instance
        return sd.OutputStream(samplerate=self.fs,
                                     blocksize=self.BLOCKSIZE,
                                     channels=1,
                                     callback=self.callback,
                                     finished_callback=self.event.set)
    
    
    # TODO - these increase and decrease methods may be combined (DRY)
    # and would just require an additional parameter
    def increase_beats_per_bar(self):
        if self.beats_per_bar < self.max_beats_per_bar:
            self.beats_per_bar += 1
            new_click_indices = np.append(self.beat_click_indices, [1])
            self.update_beat_sample_dict(new_click_indices)
        
    
    def decrease_beats_per_bar(self):
        if self.beats_per_bar > 1:
            self.beats_per_bar -= 1
            new_click_indices = self.beat_click_indices[:-1]
            self.update_beat_sample_dict(new_click_indices)
            
            # Handle quick consecutive calls. If beats_per_bar is reduced below
            # the current beat while playing, reset the current beat to 1.
            if self.current_beat > self.beats_per_bar:
                self.current_beat = 1
    
    
    def set_new_tempo(self, new_tempo_value):
        # This would be called by a Controller after the View has been updated
        # by the user to select a new tempo value using the Scale widget
        new_tempo_value = int(new_tempo_value)
        
        # Check new tempo is in valid range
        if new_tempo_value >= self.min_tempo and new_tempo_value <= self.max_tempo:
            # If not running, recompute values and reset counters for updated tempo
            if self.running == False:
                self.tempo = new_tempo_value
                self.update_values_for_new_tempo()
            
            # If running, instruct a tempo change to occur at next beat
            else:
                if new_tempo_value != self.tempo:    
                    self.new_tempo = new_tempo_value
                    self.tempo_change_pending = True
    
    
    def create_beat_click_index_array(self):
        '''
        Create the default array defining the click sounds to use. The default
        is "hi" on the first beat, followed by "lo" for every other beat in the bar.
        
        The sounds are (0: no sound, 1: lo, 2: hi)
        '''
        # Set up the default to be one hi followed by the rest lo
        return np.concatenate(([2], [1 for i in range(self.beats_per_bar - 1)])).astype(int)
    
    
    def update_beat_sample_dict(self, new_click_indices):
        '''
        Create a dictionary containing click sample audio data (zeros, lo, hi).
        This allows us to obtain the correct samples for the sound which
        should be played at each beat in a bar.
        '''
        # Update the beat_click_indices attribute 
        self.beat_click_indices = new_click_indices
        # Get a list that contains the click sound we want to use for every beat
        samples = [self.click_sounds[idx] for idx in self.beat_click_indices]
        # Create a dictionary whose keys are the beat numbers
        self.beat_sample_dict = {i+1: samples[i] for i in range(self.beats_per_bar)}
    
    
    def start(self):
        # Prevent multiple starts
        if self.running:
            return
        else:
            #print(f"Queue is empty?: {self.q.empty()}")
            # TODO - pre-fill the queue with some audio blocks
            try:
                # New - fill the queue with BUFFERSIZE blocks before playing
                self.pre_fill_queue()
                self.stream.start()
                self.running = True
            except:
                print("Error starting stream")
            
            
    def stop(self):
        if not self.running:
            return
        else:
            #print("Stopping...")
            self.running = False
            self.stream.abort()     # ends the stream quicker than stream.stop()
            self.stream.stop()      # sets the stream's active attribute to False (abort does not do this)
            self.current_beat = 0
            self.beats_at_tempo = 0
            self.bars_to_play_at_tempo = None
            self.total_samples_delivered = 0
            self.num_samples_until_next_click = 0
            # Delete the queue and make a new one to clear out the contents
            del self.q
            self.q = queue.Queue(self.BUFFERSIZE)
       
            
    def compute_drift_error_per_block(self):
        '''
        For the current tempo, calculate the drift error that occurs for every
        audio block of size self.BLOCKSIZE that is passed to the output stream.
        
        The drift error per sample is first calculated, then multiplied by
        self.BLOCKSIZE to get the total drift error for the whole audio block.
        '''
        
        samples_per_beat, decimal_component = divmod(self.fs * 60.0 / self.tempo, 1)
        error_per_sample = decimal_component / samples_per_beat
        return self.BLOCKSIZE * error_per_sample
    
        
    def update_values_for_new_tempo(self):
        '''
        Call this whenever the tempo is changed. A number of tempo-specific
        values are recalculated, and tempo-specific counters are reset.
        '''
        if self.new_tempo is not None:
            self.tempo = self.new_tempo
        self.total_samples_delivered = 0
        self.drift_error_per_block = self.compute_drift_error_per_block()
        self.beats_at_tempo = 0
        self.float_interval = self.fs * 60.0 / self.tempo
        self.interval = int(self.fs * 60.0 / self.tempo)
    
    
    def callback(self, outdata, frames, time, status):
        '''
        This is called repeatedly by the sounddevice OutputStream.
        See sounddevice docs for specifics.
        
        Blocks of audio are generated and passed to the queue, to later be
        removed from the queue as required by the OutputStream. The same data
        that is sent to the queue is also appended to self.full_output in order
        to allow analysis of the output.
        
        '''

        next_audio_block, beat = self.get_next_audio_block()
        # If the next_audio_block array contains all -1 values, we don't want
        # to actually output this one. So don't add it to the queue, and abort the callback
        # to avoid queue.Empty
        if np.all(next_audio_block==-1):
            raise sd.CallbackAbort()
        else:
            self.q.put_nowait([next_audio_block, beat])
            # Append the new audio block to full_output for later examination
            self.full_output.append(next_audio_block)
        
        assert frames == self.BLOCKSIZE
        if status.output_underflow:
            print('Output underflow: increase blocksize?', file=sys.stderr)
            raise sd.CallbackAbort
        assert not status
        try:
            # Set the beat_to_show attribute here so UI matches audio output
            data, self.beat_to_show = self.q.get_nowait()
        except queue.Empty:
            print('Buffer is empty: increase buffersize?', file=sys.stderr)
            raise sd.CallbackAbort
        if len(data) < len(outdata):
            outdata[:len(data)] = data.reshape((-1, 1))
            outdata[len(data):].fill(0)
            raise sd.CallbackStop
        else:
            outdata[:] = data.reshape((-1, 1))
        
    
    def get_current_beat(self):
        return self.current_beat


    def create_click_data_arrays(self, click_data):
        '''
        It is quite likely that the samples of a click sound (length 400 samples)
        will span more than one audio block of size 512 (self.BLOCKSIZE),
        depending on which index within a block of 512 the click sound begins.
        
        For this reason, we create a "big_arr" array of zeros and place the
        click samples at the correct indices, then chop big_arr in two so we
        can first deliver the start of the click sound, and then the "tail"
        of the click sound, in consecutive audio blocks sent to the stream.
        
        '''
        # Build the array of zeros spanning two BLOCKSIZE windows
        big_arr = np.zeros(2 * self.BLOCKSIZE)
        # Place the click data at the correct place in the big array
        big_arr[self.num_samples_until_next_click : self.num_samples_until_next_click + len(click_data)] = click_data
        # Chop big_arr in half to obtain data and tail_array
        data = big_arr[:self.BLOCKSIZE]
        tail_array = big_arr[self.BLOCKSIZE:]
        
        return data, tail_array
    
    
    def get_num_samples_until_next_click(self):
        '''
        Determine how many samples there should be between "now" and the start
        of the next click sound.
        '''
        
        # Find out how far through an interval we are
        # (how far through the space between the start of clicks)
        self.interval_samples_elapsed = self.total_samples_delivered % self.interval
        num_samples_until_next_click = self.interval - self.interval_samples_elapsed
        
        # Compensate for drift error (shift future samples to the right)
        num_samples_until_next_click += self.samples_to_shift
        
        # If this exceeds the interval size, we miss clicks. Compensate.
        if num_samples_until_next_click > self.interval:
            num_samples_until_next_click -= self.interval
        
        return int(num_samples_until_next_click)
    
    
    # New version created on 28th June
    def get_next_audio_block(self):
        '''
        This is where most of the heavy lifting is done. 
        
        '''
        # If we do not have a tail array to deliver
        # (true at first call and whenever we deliver zeros)
        if self.tail_array is None:           
            
            # Make sure we deliver a click when we first start
            if self.total_samples_delivered == 0:
                self.click_is_due_in_this_block = True
            
            # Find out how long until the next click
            if self.total_samples_delivered > 0:
                
                # Get num samples until next click scheduled to start
                self.num_samples_until_next_click = self.get_num_samples_until_next_click()
                
                # Determine if a click is needed in the audio block being constructed
                if self.num_samples_until_next_click <= self.BLOCKSIZE:
                    self.click_is_due_in_this_block = True
                else:
                    self.click_is_due_in_this_block = False
            
            
            if self.click_is_due_in_this_block:
                # If we have asked for a specific number of bars, stop when finished
                if self.bars_to_play_at_tempo is not None:                
                    if self.beats_at_tempo == self.beats_to_play_at_tempo:
                        self.stop()
                        # Once we have reached the end of our desired number of bars,
                        # return an array of all -1 values so our callback knows to abort
                        return [np.array([-1] * self.BLOCKSIZE), self.current_beat]

                
                # We can start current_beat at zero and increment at exactly 
                # the same time as the new click data being created.
                # Also means the beat number matches what we hear.
                self.current_beat = (self.current_beat % self.beats_per_bar) + 1
                self.beats_at_tempo += 1

                # Determine which sample (hi, lo, or zeros) we should hear for this beat    
                click = self.beat_sample_dict[self.current_beat]
                
                # Create the arrays containing click samples
                data, self.tail_array = self.create_click_data_arrays(click_data=click)

            else:
                # Click doesn't start in next block, so deliver a block of zeros instead
                data = self.zero_array

        
        # This means tail array is not None. Deliver the tail of the click samples
        else:
            # Assign the tail_array to the data to be returned 
            data = self.tail_array
            # Reset the attribute for the next call
            self.tail_array = None
            
            # Set and reset some things if a new tempo has been instructed
            # so we can start the new tempo immediately after this beat is
            # finished being delivered
            if self.tempo_change_pending:
                #print("Tempo change should happen now")
                self.tempo_change_pending = False
                self.update_values_for_new_tempo()
            
        # Once we get here, we have decided what the "data" array should contain
        # Update counters etc here before the next call
        self.total_samples_delivered += self.BLOCKSIZE
        self.accumulated_drift_error += self.drift_error_per_block
        
        # Compare the current accumulated drift error value to that from the previous
        # call. If the integer part of the number has changed, increment self.samples_to_shift
        prev_drift_int, _ = divmod(self.accumulated_drift_error-self.drift_error_per_block, 1)
        current_drift_int, _ = divmod(self.accumulated_drift_error, 1)
        
        if current_drift_int > prev_drift_int:
            self.samples_to_shift += 1
        
        # Add the current beat to the data array so we know which beat we
        # are actually hearing when the data is taken from queue -> speakers
        data = [data, self.current_beat]
                
        return data
        
    
    def play_for_num_bars(self, num_bars):
        # Play the click for the specified number of bars
        print(f"Number of beats required for {num_bars} bar(s) is: {num_bars * self.beats_per_bar}")
        self.bars_to_play_at_tempo = num_bars
        self.beats_to_play_at_tempo = num_bars * self.beats_per_bar
        self.start()
            
        
    def print_info(self):        
        print(f"The click sound contains {self.num_samples_in_click} samples.")
        print(f"There are {self.num_samples_until_next_click} samples until the next click should start.")
        print(f"The integer number of samples per beat is {self.interval}.")
```

## metronome_tkinter_master_GH.py

```
from metronome_master_GH import Metronome
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import glob
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class BeatSoundLabel(tk.Label):
    '''
    A subclass of tkinter's Label class, with some additional attributes
    that are used to store values related to the intended appearance of the
    label.
    
    These are index and state values which are used to retrieve images which
    are passed to the "image" parameter of the parent class's "config" method.
    
    '''
    
    def __init__(self, master, label_list_index=None, click_sound_index=0, beat_state="off"):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.label_list_index = label_list_index
        self.click_sound_index = click_sound_index
        self.beat_state = beat_state



class App():
    def __init__(self, metro: Metronome):
        self.metro = metro
        
        # Define the main window properties
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        #self.root = tk.Toplevel()
        self.root.title("Metronome")
        main_width = 750
        main_height = 650
        self.root.geometry(f"{main_width}x{main_height}")
        self.root.configure(background="black")
        
        # Define the paths for images to be loaded
        self.define_image_filepaths()
        # Load the images for the GUI
        self.load_images()
        
        # Create the StringVar that shows the current beat.
        self.beat_string_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.beat_string_var.set("")
        
        # Create these arrays using the maximum allowed beats per bar and update later
        # An array stating which click sound should be used for each beat
        self.index_array = np.concatenate(([2], np.ones(self.metro.max_beats_per_bar-1))).astype(int)
        # An array holding the state (on/off) of the illumination for each beat
        self.beat_state_array = np.array(["off" for i in range(len(self.index_array))])
        
        # Tempo frame config
        self.tempo_canvas_width = 500
        self.tempo_canvas_height = 160
        self.tempo_font_size = 60
        self.time_sig_font_size = 60
        
        # Params for coloured beat indicator labels
        self.labels = []
        self.label_width = 80
        self.label_height = 120
        
        self.beat_currently_shown = 0
        self.make_widgets()
        
        self.create_label_image_dict()
        self.populate_label_frame()
        self.set_up_keyboard_bindings()
        
        # Attach the method for handling window closing
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_window_closing)
         
        # After everything else is set up, make the displayed labels specific to the beats per bar
        for i in range(len(self.labels)-1, self.metro.beats_per_bar-1, -1):
            self.labels[i].pack_forget()
     
        
    
    def set_up_keyboard_bindings(self):
        # Bind the space bar to the ui_start_stop method
        self.root.bind("<space>", self.ui_start_stop)
        # Bind the arrow keys to adjusting the tempo
        self.root.bind("<Left>", lambda event: self.adjust_tempo(-10))
        self.root.bind("<Right>", lambda event: self.adjust_tempo(+10))
        self.root.bind("<Shift-Left>", lambda event: self.adjust_tempo(-5))
        self.root.bind("<Shift-Right>", lambda event: self.adjust_tempo(+5))
        
        self.root.bind("<Up>", lambda event: self.increment_coloured_beat_labels())
        self.root.bind("<Down>", lambda event: self.decrement_coloured_beat_labels())
    
    
    def define_image_filepaths(self):
        # Paths with multiple files for use with glob
        self.on_img_fpath = "./images/on/*.jpg"
        self.off_img_fpath = "./images/off/*.jpg"
        # Paths to specific individual images
        self.play_button_path = "./images/play_button.jpg"
        self.stop_button_path = "./images/stop_button.jpg"
        self.plus_button_path = "./images/plus_button.jpg"
        self.minus_button_path = "./images/minus_button.jpg"
        
        self.minus_5_button_path = "./images/minus_5_button.jpg"
        self.minus_10_button_path = "./images/minus_10_button.jpg"
        self.plus_5_button_path = "./images/plus_5_button.jpg"
        self.plus_10_button_path = "./images/plus_10_button.jpg"
    
    
    def load_images(self):
        self.play_button_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.play_button_path))
        self.stop_button_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.stop_button_path))
        
        # Values for resizing buttons
        new_width = 80
        new_height = int(0.676 * new_width)
        self.plus_button_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.plus_button_path).resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.minus_button_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.minus_button_path).resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.minus_5_button_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.minus_5_button_path).resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.minus_10_button_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.minus_10_button_path).resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.plus_5_button_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.plus_5_button_path).resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.plus_10_button_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.plus_10_button_path).resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    
    
    def create_label_image_dict(self):
        # Obtain filenames for images showing all possible coloured label states
        self.on_image_filenames = glob.glob(self.on_img_fpath)        
        self.off_image_filenames = glob.glob(self.off_img_fpath)

        # Create lists of PhotoImage objects for use with BeatSoundLabel objects
        self.on_images = [Image.open(path) for path in self.on_image_filenames]
        self.on_photos = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.resize((self.label_width, self.label_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)) for image in self.on_images]

        self.off_images = [Image.open(path) for path in self.off_image_filenames]
        self.off_photos = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.resize((self.label_width, self.label_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)) for image in self.off_images]

        # Place these lists in a dict
        self.img_dict = {'on': self.on_photos,
                         'off': self.off_photos}
    
    
    def make_widgets(self):
        self.build_tempo_frame()
        self.add_canvas_text()
                
        self.label_frame = tk.Frame(master=self.root)
        self.label_frame.pack(padx=0, pady=(20,20), fill=None, expand=False)
        
        # Add the text label that will show the current beat
        # beat_label = tk.Label(self.root, fg="red", bg="black", textvariable=self.beat_string_var, font=("arkitech", 48))
        # beat_label.pack()
        
        # Add a slider to control tempo, placed inside its own frame
        self.slider_frame = tk.Frame(master=self.root)
        self.slider_frame.pack()
        
        self.tempo_slider = tk.Scale(master=self.slider_frame,
                                     width=50,
                                     length=490,
                                     showvalue=False,
                                     troughcolor="#575757",
                                     from_=self.metro.min_tempo,
                                     to=self.metro.max_tempo,
                                     orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        
        self.tempo_slider.set(self.metro.tempo)
        self.tempo_slider.pack()
        # Attach the command separately to avoid the method getting called
        self.tempo_slider.configure(command=self.set_new_tempo)

        # Put a start/stop button inside a frame. Set image to a play symbol
        self.start_stop_btn_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.start_stop_btn_frame.pack(pady=(20, 20))
        self.start_stop_button = tk.Button(master=self.start_stop_btn_frame, image=self.play_button_image, highlightthickness=0, bd=0, command=self.ui_start_stop)
        self.start_stop_button.pack()
        
        # Create a frame to pack the tempo/time sig adjustment frames into
        self.adjust_button_frame = tk.Frame(master=self.root, bg='black')
        # Create a frame for each of tempo and time sig adjustment buttons
        self.tempo_adjustment_frame = tk.Frame(master=self.adjust_button_frame, bg='black')
        self.time_sig_adjustment_frame = tk.Frame(master=self.adjust_button_frame, bg='black')
        
        self.adjust_button_frame.pack()
        self.time_sig_adjustment_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(0, 13))
        self.tempo_adjustment_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(13, 0))
                
        time_sig_adjust_title = tk.Label(master=self.time_sig_adjustment_frame, text="BEATS PER BAR", fg="white", bg="black")
        tempo_adjust_title = tk.Label(master=self.tempo_adjustment_frame, text="BEATS PER MINUTE", fg="white", bg="black")
        time_sig_adjust_title.pack()
        tempo_adjust_title.pack()

        # Tempo/time sig adjustment buttons WITH images
        reduce_time_sig_button = tk.Button(master=self.time_sig_adjustment_frame, image=self.minus_button_image, highlightthickness=0, bd=0, command=self.decrement_coloured_beat_labels)
        increase_time_sig_button = tk.Button(master=self.time_sig_adjustment_frame, image=self.plus_button_image, highlightthickness=0, bd=0, command=self.increment_coloured_beat_labels)
        reduce_time_sig_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        increase_time_sig_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        # Add tempo adjustment buttons with images instead of text
        minus_10_button = tk.Button(master=self.tempo_adjustment_frame, image=self.minus_10_button_image, highlightthickness=0, bd=0, command=lambda:self.adjust_tempo(-10))
        minus_5_button = tk.Button(master=self.tempo_adjustment_frame, image=self.minus_5_button_image, highlightthickness=0, bd=0, command=lambda:self.adjust_tempo(-5))
        plus_5_button = tk.Button(master=self.tempo_adjustment_frame, image=self.plus_5_button_image, highlightthickness=0, bd=0, command=lambda:self.adjust_tempo(5))
        plus_10_button = tk.Button(master=self.tempo_adjustment_frame, image=self.plus_10_button_image, highlightthickness=0, bd=0, command=lambda:self.adjust_tempo(10))
        
        minus_10_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        minus_5_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        plus_5_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        plus_10_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        
        
    def build_tempo_frame(self):
        '''
        Build the tkinter Frame that will contain the text showing the tempo
        and time signature. The Frame contains a tkinter Canvas, where the
        text gets placed.
        '''
        self.tempo_frame = tk.Frame(master=self.root)
        self.tempo_frame.pack(anchor='center', fill='y', pady=(20,0))
        
        self.tempo_canvas = tk.Canvas(master=self.tempo_frame,
                                      bg='black',
                                      height=self.tempo_canvas_height,
                                      width=self.tempo_canvas_width)
        
        self.tempo_canvas.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        
        
    def populate_label_frame(self):
        '''
        Create a number of BeatSoundLabel objects (as many as self.max_beats_per_bar)
        and add them to a list self.labels. This list will later be used to
        show or hide the appropriate number of BeatSoundLabel objects in the
        GUI, according to self.beats_per_bar.
        '''
        # Build the initial set of BeatSoundLabel objects
        for i, click_idx in enumerate(self.index_array):
            l = BeatSoundLabel(self.label_frame,
                                label_list_index=i,
                                click_sound_index=click_idx,
                                beat_state=self.beat_state_array[i])
            
            l.config(image=self.img_dict[self.beat_state_array[i]][self.index_array[i]], bg="#a8a8a8")
            
            self.labels.append(l)
            l.pack(side='left', padx=0)
            # Bind left mouse click to cycle through sound options for this beat
            l.bind("<Button-1>", self.cycle_beat_click_sound)
    
    
    def add_canvas_text(self):
        '''
        Add text to the canvas to display information about the current tempo
        and time signature.
        '''
        # Display "tempo" title
        self.tempo_title_text = self.tempo_canvas.create_text((50, 30),
                                                              text="Tempo",
                                                                font=("Seven Segment", 14),
                                                                fill="red")
        
        # Display "time signature" title
        self.time_sig_title_text = self.tempo_canvas.create_text((400, 30),
                                                              text="Time Signature",
                                                                font=("Seven Segment", 14),
                                                                fill="red")
        
        
        # Add "empty" seven segment text underneath the tempo text
        self.tempo_bg_text = self.tempo_canvas.create_text((105, 100),
                                                            text="888",
                                                            font=("7 Segment", self.tempo_font_size),
                                                            fill="#3b110f")
        
        # Add the text to display the tempo
        self.tempo_main_text = self.tempo_canvas.create_text((105, 100),
                                                                text=str(self.metro.tempo),
                                                                font=("7 Segment", self.tempo_font_size),
                                                                fill="red")
        
        
        # Time signature background empty text
        time_sig_x_coord = 390
        self.time_sig_text = self.tempo_canvas.create_text((time_sig_x_coord, 100),
                                                        text="8 8",
                                                        font=("7 Segment", self.time_sig_font_size),
                                                        fill="#3b110f")
        
        # Time signature numerical text
        self.time_sig_text = self.tempo_canvas.create_text((time_sig_x_coord, 100),
                                                        text=f"{self.metro.beats_per_bar} 4",
                                                        font=("7 Segment", self.time_sig_font_size),
                                                        fill="red")
        
        # Time sig seven segment slash text
        self.time_sig_slash = self.tempo_canvas.create_text((time_sig_x_coord, 90),
                                                        text="/",
                                                        font=("Seven Segment", self.time_sig_font_size+10),
                                                        fill="red")
        

    def update_tempo_canvas_text(self, new_val):
        '''
        Update the tempo value shown on the canvas. Called when the tempo 
        value is updated.
        '''
        # Add a space to the start of the number if it's only 2 digits long
        if len(str(new_val)) == 2:
            new_val = " " + str(new_val)
        
        # Update the tempo value shown with seven segment font
        self.tempo_canvas.itemconfig(self.tempo_main_text, text=new_val)    
            
    
    def update_time_sig_canvas_text(self, new_val):
        '''
        Update the time signature shown on the canvas. Called when the time
        signature is updated. Note only the top number changes, as the
        note durations are always considered to be quarter notes.
        '''
        # Update the time signature value shown with seven segment font
        self.tempo_canvas.itemconfig(self.time_sig_text, text=new_val)
    
    
    def decrement_coloured_beat_labels(self):
        '''
        TODO - The GUI and metronome should not be coupled like this.
        '''
        self.metro.decrease_beats_per_bar()
        self.update_time_sig_canvas_text(new_val=f"{self.metro.beats_per_bar} 4")
        
        # Hide some labels to leave only the required number visible
        for i in range(len(self.labels)-1, self.metro.beats_per_bar-1, -1):
            self.labels[i].pack_forget()
            
            
    def increment_coloured_beat_labels(self):
        '''
        TODO - The GUI and metronome should not be coupled like this.
        '''
        self.metro.increase_beats_per_bar()
        self.update_time_sig_canvas_text(new_val=f"{self.metro.beats_per_bar} 4")
        
        # Make the requested number of labels visible
        for i in range(self.metro.beats_per_bar):
            self.labels[i].pack(side='left', padx=0)
        

    def cycle_beat_click_sound(self, event):
        '''
        This method is bound to the BeatSoundLabel instances in the GUI via 
        the left mouse click.
        
        When a BeatSoundLabel is clicked, its appearance is changed and
        the click sound associated with that beat number is updated to reflect
        this change in appearance.
        
        The GUI and metronome shouldn't be coupled like this. Have a separate
        Controller class. (to do).
        
        '''
        # Cyclically increment the click_sound_index for the label
        event.widget.click_sound_index = (event.widget.click_sound_index + 1) % 3
        # Use the new click_sound_index value to retrieve the new image to be shown
        new_image = self.img_dict[self.beat_state_array[event.widget.label_list_index]][event.widget.click_sound_index]
        event.widget.config(image=new_image)
        
        # Update the index_array so we can instruct the metronome to play the correct sound
        self.index_array[event.widget.label_list_index] = event.widget.click_sound_index
        
        # Update the metronome's dictionary that holds the samples to play on each beat
        self.metro.update_beat_sample_dict(self.index_array)
                    
            
    def set_coloured_beat_labels(self, idx=None):
        '''
        A method used to highlight exactly one of the coloured beat labels 
        to indicate the current beat number of the metronome.
        
        If idx is None, all of the labels are set to the "off" state. This is
        useful for when the metronome is not running.
        
        '''
        
        # Set all label beat states to "off"
        self.beat_state_array = np.array(["off" for i in range(len(self.index_array))])
        # Set the beat state of label at idx to "on", if specified
        if idx is not None:
            self.beat_state_array[idx] = "on"
            
        # For each label, obtain the correct image from the dictionary so that 
        # it is either highlighted or not, and it has the correct number of
        # "levels" shown, corresponding to the click sound for that beat
        for i in range(len(self.labels)):
            self.labels[i].config(image=self.img_dict[self.beat_state_array[i]][self.index_array[i]], bg="#a8a8a8")
    
    
    def increment_active_beat_label(self):
        # Update beat labels so the label for the current beat is highlighted
        # First, set them all to be "off"
        self.set_coloured_beat_labels(idx=None)
        
        # Get the index corresponding to the current beat (only syncs without pre-filling queue)
        # if self.metro.get_current_beat() != 0:
        #     label_idx = self.metro.get_current_beat() - 1
        
        # Use beat_to_show when pre-filling the queue with audio blocks
        if self.metro.beat_to_show != 0:
            label_idx = self.metro.beat_to_show - 1
        else:
            label_idx = 0
        
        # Highlight the correct label
        self.set_coloured_beat_labels(idx=label_idx)
    

    def update_beat_number_from_metro(self):
        '''
        Use the current beat number from the Metronome object to update the
        text label that shows the current beat in the GUI. tkinter's "after"
        method is used here to check for an updated beat number every 10ms.
        There's nothing special about this duration, it just seems to work nicely.
        '''
        
        #beat_to_show = self.metro.get_current_beat()
        # Use beat_to_show when pre-filling the queue with audio blocks
        beat_to_show = self.metro.beat_to_show
        
        # This is a bit of a hack. Don't display beat 0 - change it to 1
        if beat_to_show == 0:
            beat_to_show = 1

        if self.beat_currently_shown != beat_to_show:
            self.increment_active_beat_label()
            
        self.beat_string_var.set(beat_to_show)
        self.after_loop = self.root.after(10, self.update_beat_number_from_metro)
        
        # Set this for comparison in the next call to check if we increment blue label
        self.beat_currently_shown = beat_to_show
        
    
    def set_new_tempo(self, new_val):
        # TODO - decouple GUI from metronome
        if int(new_val) > self.metro.max_tempo or int(new_val) < self.metro.min_tempo:
            return
        self.metro.set_new_tempo(new_val)
        self.update_tempo_canvas_text(new_val)
        # Setting the tempo slider value in this way calls this method I think
        # Could use a tk.DoubleVar to prevent this?
        self.tempo_slider.set(new_val)
        # Debugging print       
        # print(f"In set_new_tempo: {self.metro.tempo}")
    
    
    def adjust_tempo(self, adjustment):
        '''
        Make adjustments to the tempo rather than specifying an absolute tempo
        value. This is connected to the buttons to move +/- N bpm.
        '''
        new_tempo = int(self.tempo_slider.get() + adjustment)  
        self.set_new_tempo(new_tempo)
    
    
    def start(self):
        if not self.metro.running:
            self.metro.start()
            # Update the coloured labels to show the first beat blue
            self.set_coloured_beat_labels(idx=0)
            self.update_beat_number_from_metro()
    
    
    def stop(self):
        if self.metro.running:
            self.metro.stop()
            self.root.after_cancel(self.after_loop)
            # Blank out the displayed beat number and the coloured labels
            self.beat_string_var.set("")
            self.set_coloured_beat_labels(idx=None)
    
    
    def ui_start_stop(self, event=None):
        if self.metro.running:
            # Stop the metronome and update the button image
            self.stop()
            self.start_stop_button.config(image=self.play_button_image)
        else:
            # Start the metronome and update the button image
            self.start()
            self.start_stop_button.config(image=self.stop_button_image)
    
    
    def on_window_closing(self):
        # Stop the metronome when the user closes the window
        self.stop()
        self.root.destroy()
```

## main.py

```
from metronome_master_GH import Metronome
from metronome_tkinter_master_GH import App

metronome = Metronome(tempo=180, beats_per_bar=4)
app = App(metronome)
app.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're soliciting advice from random internet strangers on this code, when you already have an action plan for improving it, e.g. shrink the `__init__` constructors. Go improve docstrings and introduce `_private` attributes and so on, then come back and solicit a critique. You will obtain better advice that way. // Many of the per-object attributes look like they could be class attributes, e.g. `min_beats_per_bar`. // Running `$ isort *.py` and `$ black -S *.py` prior to submission would reduce review friction a little, would make things more uniform.

Comment: Try to flatten code out. Instead of `if self.tail_array is None: <50 lines of indented code>` try `if self.tail_array is not None: return` then de-indent the 50 lines that come after it. Try to lower cyclomatic complexity.

Comment: @J_H thanks for your comment. For some of the observations I stated, I was looking for advice on *how* they could be done. For example, best practices on contents of `__init__` methods in cases like this (is it a bad thing that it is long? If so, please help me understand how I can effectively shrink it). Also feedback about the longer methods e.g. `get_next_audio_block` where it feels like there is too much in there but it is not clear to me how to split it up.

Comment: @ggorlen thanks for commenting. In this particular case, when the condition you mentioned evaluates to `False`, the result is not simply `return`. I can see that your suggestion is good to look out for in general though.

Comment: @dg0802 I missed that, but it proves my point--I have to scan down 50 lines to find that single line dangling out the blue yonder. `else` can mostly be done away with any time there's a `return` in the `if`, flattening out the code and removing complexity.

Answer (score 1):

## standard plus pypi import sections

```
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
import audiofile
import sys
import queue
import threading
```

[pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports) essentially asks you to
[isort](https://pypi.org/project/isort) this, please.

While you're at it, may as well do
"$ [black](https://pypi.org/project/black) -S *.py",
verify you're happy to commit it, then do a trivial "quotes" commit using
"$ black *.py".

---

## class docstring

```
class Metronome():
    def __init__(self, tempo=180, beats_per_bar=4):
```

Thank you for the convenient parameter defaulting.
Consider type hinting that we accept `float` and `int`.

But look at what's missing!
You passed up the opportunity to offer a """docstring""".
Why is it important?
You will write an English sentence that gives the
[single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)
of this class.

You lamented that perhaps some things became "too big".
Well, [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)
is here to help with that.
Once you've written the sentence,
it becomes a rubric you can apply to each line of code,
asking "does *this* belong in this class?"
If the answer is "no", that's an opportunity
to create a new class and assign *it* such a responsibility.

As a general rule of thumb, we strive to make `__init__` ctors
and other methods fit within a single screenful of code,
so we can read all of it without scrolling.
Going much beyond fifty-ish lines tends to suggest
it's time to extract one or more helper methods.

It almost seems that the only attribute we neglected to initialize
was `self.kitchen_sink`. Once a piece of code starts to become a
dumping ground, we see a "rich get richer" effect, all the new
variables wind up there so they can hang out with the other variables.
Articulating the Single Responsibility in a docstring is the
simplest way to nip that effect in the bud,
making it clear at once that no, some proposed attribute doesn't belong there.

## class attributes

```
        # Define limits for tempo and beats_per_bar
        self.min_tempo = 10
        self.max_tempo = 350
        self.min_beats_per_bar = 1
        self.max_beats_per_bar = 8
```

These look like they're global across all Metronome objects,
and could live at the class level.

BTW, you write a fair number of helpful `# comments`, and that can be Good.
But at review time you might choose to view
each `# Reticulate the splines` comment as an opportunity to
break out a `def reticulate_splines(self):` helper method.
That can shrink a giant method down to a screenful of code,
can reduce coupling due to method-local temp variables that
go out of scope upon returning, and it makes
[unit testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)
easier.

Constants like `BLOCKSIZE` and `BUFFERSIZE`
definitely belong at the class level.

## math notation

```
        if tempo < self.min_tempo or tempo > self.max_tempo:
            raise Exception( ... )
```

Prefer to express a closed interval with more compact mathematical notation:

```
        if not (self.min_tempo <= tempo <= self.max_tempo):
```

Now it's easier to read, as "if not in interval".

The trouble with an app reporting an `Exception` is it's not very specific.
It covers just about
[everything](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy).
Much better to define an app-specific error class,
or in this particular case better to use the existing `ValueError`
since it fits what's happening here.

We habitually do this so that at some point,
when it turns out a caller actually wants to `try` catch an error
and intelligently recover from it, the caller can narrowly focus
on just the case it anticipates.
BTW, kudos on a nice diagnostic message.

Ok, possibly some more bloat,
I'm skeptical that `new_tempo` and `tempo_change_pending`
really need to be here.
They seem to come at the start of a section devoted
to the low-level audio details of hi-lo tick-tock sounds.
Maybe we'd like to focus on "things that matter to the end user"
in this class, such as `tempo` plus currently `running`,
and push nitty-gritty audio details down into another class.

Thank you for the "# sample rate of audio, in Hz" comment
which explains that `fs` means "frequency of sampling".

And then we come to `zero_array`, which is all about assembling an audio waveform.
Ok, it's starting to look like `__init__` is tackling perhaps
four broad areas of responsbility:

- UX parameters, like tempo and whether we're currently running
- producing a waveform based on the tempo
- playing that waveform
- modeling drift error details of the playback

Consider creating classes with more narrowly focused responsibilities.

You have lots of small methods defined, so congratulations, that much is very good.
One approach to improving coupling of object attributes
would be to move one method at a time,
move the attributes it consumes,
and look at red underlines in the IDE to see what other methods that breaks.
You may notice a clique of three or four methods that interact with each other
but not with strangers, suggesting that they belong in their own class.
And of course a caller can always pass `self.this` or `self.that`
into a method when calling it, if some value is used by more than a single class.

Rather than calling `update_values_for_new_tempo`,
consider creating a brand new `Tempo` object.

---

## logging

```
            # Debugging print statements to check output
            # print(f"Mean: {np.mean(next_audio_block)}")
            # print(f"Queue size before putting: {self.q.qsize()}")
```

Keeping such debugs as part of the released production code
can be helpful to maintenance engineers months down the road.
Consider creating a [logger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)
so we can crank verbosity up to DEBUG or down to WARN, as needed.

---

## numeric type

In `set_new_tempo` it's not obvious to me why
the tempo couldn't be a `float`, but fine, them's the rules.
Consider adding type hints, and checking them with
[mypy](https://pypi.org/project/mypy).

```
            if self.running == False:
```

Idiomatic code will prefer to phrase it as:

```
            if not self.running:
```

---

## context handler

```
    def start(self):
        # Prevent multiple starts
        if self.running:
            return
        else:
```

I like this.
I'm sure it fulfills some need, like double-clicking a button
would lead to unfortunate audio effects.

But I wonder if maybe it's more of a band-aid than a design,
and that the "no double play!" responsibility would be better
allocated to the caller.
That is, perhaps a
[with](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager)
`@contextmanager` should take care to always `.close()`
a metronome or to check that it's not busy, rather that do it here.
Either way works, so no biggie.

Consider striking the `else:`, so the rest of
the method body can be out-dented a little.

```
            except:
                print("Error starting stream")
```

No.

https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/bare-except.html

> A bare `except:` clause will catch `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt` exceptions, making it harder to interrupt a program with `Control-C`, and can disguise other problems.

Prefer `except Exception:` instead.
Or `except Exception as e:` so you can include `e` in the diagnostic message.
Or just catch the one or two particular errors that you're actually anticipating,
so "surprise" errors give us an informative stack trace.

It appears you may set `running` True a bit late; you might want
to assign it prior to prefilling the queue and starting the stream.
As written it looks a bit
[racy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Data_race).
Similarly, I wonder if `stop()` maybe sets it a bit early.

Notice that `stop()` is aware of many attributes which it must reset.
If many of them were in, say, a `Tempo` object,
then setting that to `None` might suffice.
Or perhaps we'd like a `def close` method which knows some of those attributes.
It all comes back to the contract defined by docstrings you write,
which will spell out the invariants that hold while audio is playing.

---

## properties

```
    def update_values_for_new_tempo(self):
        '''
        Call this whenever the tempo is changed. A number of tempo-specific
        values are recalculated, and tempo-specific counters are reset.
        '''
```

A docstring, wonderful!
You have a bunch of nice docstrings on some of these methods, and I applaud them.
(Ok, strictly speaking we're looking for one English sentence, a blank line,
and then rambling commentary, but hey, I'll take it. It is helpful.)

I'm going to quibble with the "call whenever" aspect of this method.
It just sounds like we're designing a "hard to consume" API,
if we need to stay cognizant of carefully sequenced method calls
at just the right times.

It comes back to maintaining
[class invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_invariant),
which we write down in docstrings and comments.
What if `interval` was *guaranteed* to **always** be correct?
So my proposal is, couldn't we use a `@property` to report
things like `interval` ?
Maybe a [setter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)
should zero out those counters?

---

## choose informative names

```
    def callback(self, outdata, frames, time, status):
```

This is *accurate*.
But it doesn't help me to understand when it will be called,
nor what its responsibility is.
Consider naming it `generate_audio_callback`.

And though your docstrings are usually quite helpful,
this one is a bit opaque.
I would love to see this URL appear in docstring or as comment:
https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.4.6/api/streams.html#sounddevice.OutputStream

There is some very nice {underflow, empty} error reporting,
for blocksizes that turn out to be too small.
I wonder if we could track minimum queue depth here,
so that at the end we could report that the chosen
blocksize was wildly too large.

---

## simplify boolean assignment

In `get_next_audio_block`

```
        if self.num_samples_until_next_click <= self.BLOCKSIZE:
            self.click_is_due_in_this_block = True
        else:
            self.click_is_due_in_this_block = False
```

a single assignment would suffice:

```
        self.click_is_due_in_this_block = self.num_samples_until_next_click <= self.BLOCKSIZE
```

Or if you feel it should be more explicit, assign `... = bool( ... )`.

This is kind of a long method.
Maybe you can find a few lines that can be extracted to a helper method?

---

This code appears to achieve its design goals.

Given the the "kitchen sink" approach to API design, and the lack of
[unit tests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)
for helpers which would support refactors, in its current form I would be reluctant to delegate
maintenance tasks on this codebase to a junior dev.